# Prove that $f$ is identically equal to $0$ on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

I was given $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0$ for all continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$.

How do I prove that $f$ is identically equal to $0$ on $[a,b]$?

I tried to assume $f$ does not equal to $0$ to get a contradiction, but got stuck. Can I reach this problem with a different approach?

Comment: See what you can deduce from taking $g=f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: If $\int_a^b fg=0$ for all $g$ continuous on $[a,b]$ then

$$\int_a^b f(x)^2dx=0.$$

Comment: Can I let $\epsilon={|f(t)|\over 2}$ and then do it by cases, and get $\int_a^bf(x)^2dx$ either $<0$ or $>0$, which is a contradiction?

Comment: $f(x)^2=|f(x)|^2$ since $f$ is continuous if its non-zero you can bound it below by $\varepsilon>0$ in some small interval, then this gives that the integral must be positive.

Comment: So, it's clear that $\int_a^bf(x)^2dx$ can never be negative,, right? Do I need to state that?

Comment: If $g\geq 0$ then $\int_a^b g(x)dx \geq 0$ assuming $a<b$ of course. You should be able to prove it, but you can most likely state it.

Comment: and from $\int_a^bf(x)^2dx=0$, I can just infer that $f(x)^2=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the contradiction route, here's one. Assume there is some $c\in (a, b)$ s.t. $f(c) \neq 0$. Just for simplicity's sake, say $f(c)\gt 0$.

By definition of continuity, there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that for any $x \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$, we have $f(x) > 0$. Let $g$ be a function which is $0$ outside that interval, and positive within the interval. Then
$$
\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx
$$
is strictly positive. Thus we have a contradiction. (The case $f(c)< 0$ is completely analogous, only the integral is strictly negative. Still, we have a contradiction.)

An example of a $g$ with the properties we want (just to convince you that it exists) is the funtion which is equal to $0$ outside the interval $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$, and within the interval is equal to $\epsilon^2 - (x-c)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Then $ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx = 0 $. If $ f $ is not null, there exist $ x \in [a,b]: f(x)^2 >0 $ by continuidty $ f>c $ in some interval $ I \subset \Omega $. Thus $ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx \ge  \int_{a}^{b}c^2 = c^2 |I| > 0 $. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is for each $x \in (a,b)$, construct a sequence of continuous functions (say piecewise linear) $\{p_n\}$ with the property that $\int_a^b f(y) p_n(y) dy \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.  Basically, we want a sequence of functions of total integral 1 so that the majority of the mass of these functions is contained in increasingly smaller intervals around $x$.