A sufficient condition for $f = 0$ when its integral is zero.
Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b} fg = 0$ for every continuous function $g$ on $[a, b]$. Prove that $f = 0$.
My attempt: since $\int_{a}^{b} fg = 0$ for every continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$, in particular taking $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ we get
$$
0 = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.
$$
Now to finish the proof I assume that I have to use the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous. What comes to my mind is the mean value theorem for integrals, to get a point $c \in (a, b)$ such that
$$
0 = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = f(c)(b-a),
$$
from what I can conclude that $f(c) = 0$, but this holds for some  $c$, not for all of them. How should I proceed?

$0 = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$  does not imply that $f=0$. Better choose $g=f$.

This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538728/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009922/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253157/42969 – all found with Approach0

I see, thank you. Now it is straightforward, since for $f=g$ one gets $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2} = 0$ and since the map $(f,g) \mapsto \int_{a}^{b}fg$ is an inner product it is positive definite, so $f=0$ for the equality to make sense.
